# So simple but how

Tags: html, forms

I have a plethora of language-agnostic programming information in my mind, though no language specific paradigms. If you could help me out I'd really appreciate it!

How would I:

Have on a web page, on each link clicked from the menu, give the user the chance to:
 - Enter their name 
 - Click send
 - Display a thank you message 
 - Give them a chance to enter their email at the end to receive a free gift (an email and then an ebook)

In the fastest, lightest way possible on a mobile browser

And how would I get the information in a database?

Comment: I suggest before coming to stackoverflow, go ahead and see w3schools and learn HTML, Javascript and PHP. The basic of those languages would give you everything you need.

Comment: Your question is too broad. As you can see by Dominick's comment and Edub's "answer", you need to pick a server side language … and people have very different opinions about which is best.

Comment: Thank you Dominick for you insight, it is appreciated. Quentin, what would you recommend as a serve side language?

Comment: @user7234971 — Shopping questions and opinion based questions are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Me throwing in my opinion about what is best for you wouldn't be very helpful because (a) I don't know anything about your background (b) I don't know anything about your server configuration or your ability to change it and (c) I don't know anything about who you might be working with and what their backgrounds are. (I do think that PHP is awful, and that a MEAN stack is a relatively specialised tool, and that MonogoDB in particular sounds rather unsuited to your problem (compared to a RDBMS)).

Comment: Thank you for your honesty and insight Quentin I appreciate the information. I simply need to have a user type their name, hit send, and have that be put on a numbered list updated live to me personally. I don't mean to be ambiguous, I apologize. I don't have any true programming experience other than some HTML and a tiny bit of Objective-c. Right now I'm only hosting with Hostgator, one of the basic plans. I'm not working with anyone, but once this is presented I anticipate a large team, more resources, or both.

Answer (score -1):

Get started a MEAN stack and host it.
MEAN = MongoDB (Database), Express (Webserver), A(ngular) and N(ode).
That's the way I would do it, most likly you would use Bootstrap or Material to make it responsive (good experience on a mobile device).